# Проблема с отправкой сообщений в чате

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

при вводе сообщения в форму и нажатия кнопки "отправить", сообщение не создается, и, соответственно, не отображается в окне. то, что сообщение не создается, проверено по логам и консоли - в логах идет запрос в бд SELECT "messages". * FROM "messages" ORDER_BY created_at ASC, при запросе в консоли  Message.find(:id), например 1, или 2, или 3 - выдает ошибку, так как сообщение создано не было.

модель `Message` принадлежит модели `User`

**`controllers/messages_controller.rb`**:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @message = Message.new
        @messages = Message.all.order('created_at ASC')
    end
    def create
        if current_user
            @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
            if @message.save
                flash[:success] = 'created successfully'
            else
                flash[:error] = 'oops, an error!'
            end
        end
        redirect_to root_path
    end
    private
        def message_params
            params.require(:message).permit(:body)
        end
end
```

**`index.html.erb`**:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="media-list">
            <%= render @messages %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**`_message.html.erb`**

```
<li class="media-message">
    <%= link_to image_tag(message.user.avatar_url, alt: message.user.name, class: "media-object"),
          message.user.profile_url, target: '_blank', class: 'pull-left' %>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
            <%= link_to message.user.name, message.user.profile_url, target: '_blank' %> says
            <small class="text-muted">[at <%= message.created_at.strftime('%-d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S') %>]</small>
        </h4>
        <p><%= message.body %></p>
    </div>
</li>
```

http://khersonchat.herokuapp.com/ сайт

**`$ heroku logs`**

```
User Load (5.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   
"authenticity_token"=>"XYtmzo3Fq2psbRUWNR8w8iZFSVIIbjxAKX+Q7psmB5vWxXtFO8r2hLASGEPypomWt/L0wKHmI3d7+D1kw0Kiiw==", 
"message"=>{"body"=>"Hello world!"}, "commit"=>"Отправить"}
Started POST "/messages" for 134.249.158.132 at 2016-03-31 17:30:48 +0000
(1.8ms)  BEGIN
(2.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://khersonchat.herokuapp.com/
Completed 302 Found in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 9.9ms)
Started GET "/" for 134.249.158.132 at 2016-03-31 17:30:48 +0000
Processing by MessagesController#new as HTML
at=info method=POST path="/messages" 
    host=khersonchat.herokuapp.com 
    request_id=dcef82d9-4ff0-4319-88f6-f8c547db7867
    fwd="134.249.158.132" 
    dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=53ms status=302 bytes=1168
Rendered collection (0.0ms)
Rendered messages/_form.html.erb (1.2ms)
Message Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"  ORDER BY created_at ASC
User Load (3.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Rendered messages/new.html.erb within layouts/application (17.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 11.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

Comment: *при инициализации новое сообщение не создается* <- эм, что?

Comment: @D-side, прошу прощения, просто сижу над этой ошибкой и уже мозги потекли :( попытаюсь объяснить, как адекватный человек - когда ввожу текст сообщения в форму, и нажимаю на кнопку "отправить", сообщение не создается, и, соответственно, не отображается в окне. то, что сообщение не создается, я проверял по логам и консоли - в логах идет запрос в бд `SELECT "messages". * FROM "messages" ORDER_BY created_at ASC`, но когда в консоли пытаюсь найти сообщение - `Message.find(:id)`, ну например 1, или 2, или 3 - выдает ошибку, так как сообщение создано не было

Comment: Так при создании там комбо begin/insert/commit имеется в логах?

Comment: @D-side, увы, нет. и я никак не могу понять, в чем ошибка :( несколько раз перепроверил контроллер и модели

Comment: Ок, тогда приведите сами логи, почитаем.

Comment: @D-side добавлено

Comment: Begin/rollback значит, что `save` не состоялся. Обычно из-за валидаций, которых в вопросе тоже нет.

Comment: @D-side храни Вас Господь! я посмотрел валидации, и увидел, что я вместо `length: { maximum: 2000 }` написал `length: { minimum: 2000 }`. трудно быть идиотом!

Comment: Если понадоблюсь, обращайтесь на Бейкер-стрит, 221Б. И приносите исходники! А лучше всё-таки освойте отладчик. .-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в валидациях. вместо `length: { maximum: 2000 }` я указал `length: { minimum: 2000 }`. всегда нужно внимательно вычитывать код! :)